# Communication between JVMTI agent and separate JVM

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, rmi, jvmti

First off i apologize as this is somewhat answered already here, but I think my situation is a bit different.

[How to communicate with jvmti agent attached on a running JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585199/how-to-communicate-with-jvmti-agent-attached-on-a-running-jvm)

My main question is...
I am wondering if there are anyways using the JNI or other libraries to communicate between a JVMTI Native Agent and a completely separate JVM.

Here is a small illustration

[image]

So whats happening here. 
The JVM on the left is loaded with a native agent. Just for discussion sake let's assume I have no access to the source code of this java application. So instead I use the Java Native Agent to garner information from the objects.

Now I want to transfer the information to the JVM on the right. Represented by the broken link. Ideally i'd like to call a method on JVM2, have the Native Agent load information from JVM1 and then return it to JVM2.

I'm pretty sure I can do this with sockets, but I was just wondering if I had any other options here such as using JNI and registering native agents or something like mentioned in the previous answer.

Comment: What is it you want to do?

Comment: Communicate java objects between the jvmti agent and the separate jvm

Comment: I think I can actually wrap JMX client in a java-agent and invoke the data transfer that way..

Comment: What is the goal you want to reach?

Comment: i dont know how to be more specific.

Comment: Give a detailled example like  "I would like to know X about the Tomcat instance running in JVM1".

Comment: There is a static string inside JVM1, I can get that string with Java JVMTI agent. Now I need to transfer that string to JVM2

Answer (score 1):

So since nobody replied, I'll just post here that I'm gonna use Sockets.

Here is an example I used.

[sending doubles via TCP between Boost ASIO server and Java client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131653/sending-doubles-via-tcp-between-boost-asio-server-and-java-client)