# Can Someone give an actual implementation of the pseudo code to convert Host byte order to network byte Order

Tags: c++11, double, htonl

The Stable Pseudo Code is this mentioned on the following link.
I would like to implement it in c++. I am not able to understand and perform these signof and exponentof and mantissaof operations.

[how to convert double between host and network byte order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616883/how-to-convert-double-between-host-and-network-byte-order)

```
void htond (const double hostDouble, uint8_t result[8])
{
  result[0] = signOf(hostDouble);
  result[1] = exponentOf(hostDouble);
  result[2..7] = mantissaOf(hostDouble);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the sign (even for negative zeros) use `std::signbit()`.

To extract the exponent, use `std::frexp()` (or `std::ilogb()` for non-power-of-two radix). Note that you have to handle zero, infinity and NaN as special cases.

The mantissa can be obtained with `std::abs(std::ldexp(value, -exponent))` (or `std::scalbn()` for a non-power-of-two radix); this will produce a fraction normalized (with a range depending on what function you used to extract the exponent).

Comment: Can you give me a working code, with example inputs like: 1000000015949038, 1000000015949030 etc.