# How to change double's endianness?

Tags: c, endianness

I need to read data from serial port. They are in little endian, but I need to do it platform independent, so I have to cover the endianness of `double`. I couldn't find anywhere, how to do it, so I wrote my own function. But I am not sure with it. (and I don't have a machine with big endian to try it on).

Will this work correctly? or is there some better approach I wasn't able to find?

```
double get_double(uint8_t * buff){
    double value;
    memcpy(&value,buff,sizeof(double));
    uint64_t tmp;
    tmp = le64toh(*(uint64_t*)&value);
    value = *(double*) &tmp;
    return value;
}
```

p.s. I count with `double` 8 bytes long, so don't bother with this pls. I know that there might be problems with this

EDIT: After suggestion, that I should use union, I did this:

```
union double_int{
    double d;
    uint64_t i;
};


double get_double(uint8_t * buff){
    union double_int value;
    memcpy(&value,buff,sizeof(double));
    value.i = le64toh(value.i);
    return value.d;
}
```

better? (though I don't see much of a difference)

EDIT2: attemtp #3, what do you think now?

```
double get_double(uint8_t * buff){
    double value;
    uint64_t tmp;
    memcpy(&tmp,buff,sizeof(double));
    tmp = le64toh(tmp);
    memcpy(&value,&tmp,sizeof(double));
    return value;
}
```

Edit3: I compile it with `gcc -std=gnu99 -lpthread -Wall -pedantic`

Edit4: After next suggestion I added a condition for endianness order checking. I honestly have no idea, what I am doing right now (shouldn't there be something like `__DOUBLE_WORD_ORDER__` ?)

```
double get_double(uint8_t * buff){
    double value;
    if (__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__){
        uint64_t tmp;
        memcpy(&tmp,buff,sizeof(double));
        tmp = le64toh(tmp);
        memcpy(&value,&tmp,sizeof(double));
    }
    else {
        memcpy(&value,buff,sizeof(double));
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: You should use a union

Comment: I did it as you suggested... better? it looks better, but I don't see a significant diffference

Comment: There are aliasing rules, and the alignment requirements of an `uint64_t` could be different from `double` (improbable, yes), and so on.

Comment: ok, so now, as I did it with union, It's goona work?

Comment: Better using memcpy or something else. With usions you can have problem with some GCC versions and -O3 optimization enabled.

Comment: memcpy rather than what? Sry, I didn't get you.

Comment: Copy double to uint64_t then convert by le64toh uint64_t and copy back to double.
"memcpy rather than what? " union

Comment: ok, so now its better?

Comment: Ah: you need to force at least -std=c99, as in C89 this has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why the union bother? It is fine to cast any pointer to a char pointer (and then do what you want with the memory, e.g. memcpy it around); that's explicitly allowed as an exception to the normal aliasing restrictions, and C would not work without it, nor would any program written in C. Cf. n1570, 6.5/7.

Comment: Calling `le64toh()` adjusts,the endian of an _integer_ depending of the endianness of the platform versus "network".  The endian-ness of a `double` is **independent** of an integer.  `le64toh()` might be useful to perform an endian swap, but not to detect if it is needed for `double`.

Comment: The `union` concerns are useful for avoiding the `memcpy(&tmp,buff,sizeof(double));` step, but not the "endian" step.

Comment: ive just edited the question, is it correct now?

Comment: Edit 3 was useful as it added missing information. Edits 1,2,4 changed the question repeatedly.  Moving targets are frown upon in SO.

Comment: I meant the code in the 4th edit...

Comment: @Charlestone If you have an answer to your own (original)  question, post your answer in the _answer_ section.  This way all can votes on your Q & A independently.  Editing your own post with an ever improving answer is not the SO model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just go and copy the bytes manually to a temporary double and then return that. In C (and I think C++) it is fine to cast any pointer to `char *`; that's one of the explicit permissions for aliasing (in the standard draft n1570, par. 6.5/7), as I mentioned in one of my comments. The exception is absolutely necessary in order to get anything done that is close to hardware; including reversing bytes received over a network :-).

There is no standard compile time way to determine whether that's necessary which is a pity; if you want to avoid branches which is probably a good idea if you deal with lots of data, you should look up your compiler's documentation for proprietary defines so that you can choose the proper code branch at compile time. [gcc, for example,](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) has `__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__` set to either `__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__` or `__ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__`.

(Because of your question in comments: `__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__` means floating points in general. It would be a very sick mind who designs a FPU that has different byte orders for different data sizes :-). In all reality there aren't many mainstream architectures which have different byte orders for floating point vs. integer types. As Wikipedia says, small systems may differ.)

Basile pointed to `ntohd`, a conversion function which exists on Windows but apparently not on Linux.

My naive sample implementation would be like

```
/** copy the bytes at data into a double, reversing the
    byte order, and return that.
*/
double reverseValue(const char *data)
{
    double result;

    char *dest = (char *)&result;

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(double); i++) 
    {
        dest[i] = data[sizeof(double)-i-1];
    }
    return result;
}

/** Adjust the byte order from network to host.
    On a big endian machine this is a NOP.
*/
double ntohd(double src)
{
#   if      !defined(__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__) \
        ||  !defined(__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__)
#       error "oops: unknown byte order"
#   endif

#   if __FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
        return reverseValue((char *)&src);
#   else
        return src;
#   endif
}
```

There is a working example here: https://ideone.com/aV9mj4.

An improved version would cater to the given CPU -- it may have an 8 byte swap command.

Comment: Rather than `#error`, I'd rather fallback to a run-time test.

Comment: @black True. I was happy to have "error handling" at all in this example :-)

Comment: Note: Using `"%le"` rather than `"%lf"`is more illustrative for the linked example.

Answer (score 1):

If you can adapt the software both sides (emitter & receiver) you could use some [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) library and format. It could be using old [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) routines like `xdr_double` in your case (see [xdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/xdr_double.3.html)...). You could also consider [ASN1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) or using textual formats like [JSON](http://json.org/).

XDR is [big endian](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.1/general_topics/wkb_representation.htm). You might try to find some [NDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Data_Representation) implementation, is is little endian.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10616883/841108) related question, and STFW for `htond`

Comment: unfortunetly I can not. Emmiter is a GPS reciever.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so finally, thanks to you all, I have found the best solution. Now my code looks like this:

```
double reverseDouble(const char *data){
    double result;
    char *dest = (char *)&result;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(double); i++) 
        dest[i] = data[sizeof(double)-i-1];
    return result;
}

double get_double(uint8_t * buff){
    double value;
    memcpy(&value,buff,sizeof(double));

    if (__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__)
        return reverseDouble((char *)&value);
    else
        return value;
}
```

p.s. (checking for defines etc. is somewhere else)

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume the endianness of doubles is the same as for integers (which you can't, generally, but it's almost always the same), you can read it as an integer by shifting it byte by byte, and then cast the representation to a double.

```
double get_double_from_little_endian(uint8_t * buff) {
    uint64_t u64 = ((uint64_t)buff[0] << 0  |
                    (uint64_t)buff[1] << 8  |
                    (uint64_t)buff[2] << 16 |
                    (uint64_t)buff[3] << 24 |
                    (uint64_t)buff[4] << 32 |
                    (uint64_t)buff[5] << 40 |
                    (uint64_t)buff[6] << 48 |
                    (uint64_t)buff[7] << 56);
    return *(double *)(char *)&u64;
}
```

This is only standard C and it's optimized well by compilers. The C standard doesn't define how the floats are represented in memory though, so compiler-dependent macros like `__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__` may give better results, but it gets more complex if you want to cover also the "mixed-endian IEEE format" which is found on ARM old-ABI.